# Modify property of MainWindow from UserControl

Tags: wpf, parent

I am creating a UserControl, I want that when I click in a button from that Control a property (attriibute) modifies from my MainWindow. The UserControl is created from a separate project and built as a .dll.

I had tried the following:

```
Window l = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

The problem is that because my window is not being referenced I have no way to access it (the properties I had created) and I dont know how to do it. If I try to write "MainWindow" it says that it couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can get window using **`Application.Current.MainWindow`**. It will return window object so make sure you typecast it to actual instance of your window.

Assuming actual instance is `MainWindow`, it can be accessed like this:

```
MainWindow window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Comment: It says that it can't be found, I think that is becase in my user control there is no reference to my main project, how do I reference them?

Comment: Is your userControl added as a child of MainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of ways of accessing a reference to the main `Window` in WPF. There is the way that @Rohit Vats showed you:

```
MainWindow window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

However, as you have noticed, this does *not* always work. Sometimes it can be fixed simply by setting the property to the `MainWindow` instance:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
}
```

You should now be able to access the `MainWindow` from this property. However, if that *still* doesn't work for some reason, then you can also try the [`Application.Windows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach (MainWindow window in Application.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>())
{
    // Do something with window here
}
```